When reconnecting the cable, iPhone USB status shows as "Attached" with a yellow icon, only turns green after a reboot
When I initially connect my iPhone 14 Pro via USB to my M1 Pro running Sonoma, everything works great: the Network tab shows the status of "iPhone USB" as "Connected" with a green icon:

However if I unplug the cable and insert it again, it will show up as "Attached" with a yellow icon. The only fix I've found is to reboot the Mac after which it will work again:

Is there a way fix this without having to reboot my Mac every time I reconnect the cable? Maybe I could just restart some networking service instead?

This can be fixed by running the following command:
sudo networksetup -setmanual 'iPhone USB' 192.0.0.50 255.255.255.255 192.0.0.1

This will force the IP to be set to 192.0.0.50, allowing the two devices to sync. Afterwards you can re-enable DHCP again:
sudo networksetup -setdhcp 'iPhone USB'

The same trick applies to fix Wi-Fi tethering, except you'd instead run
sudo networksetup -setmanual 'Wi-Fi' 192.0.0.50 255.255.255.255 192.0.0.1

